# .obj/.gltf 3D model won't show in ARCore

Tags: java, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I followed a tutorial online to create an AR app that could show my 3D models in AR.

I put my .obj and .gltf 3d model files in my assets folder,

when the I tap on a plane, the method placeObject() should run and put my model (selectObject) on the place.

but when I test it on my phone,after the plane was detected and I tapped the screen, nothing happened, I checked my logcat and it shows the error when I tapped:

```
2021-11-04 01:55:46.629 11172-12363/com.example.arcoretest E/ModelRenderable: Unable to load Renderable registryId='testscene.obj'
    java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.AssertionError: No RCB file at uri: testscene.obj
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:284)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1629)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: No RCB file at uri: testscene.obj
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.byteBufferToSfb(LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.java:191)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.lambda$downloadAndProcessRenderable$0$com-google-ar-sceneform-rendering-LoadRenderableFromSfbTask(LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.java:121)
```

I'm not sure where the problem is, is it my uri is wrong or I should use other 3d model format?
(I tried .obj/.fbx/.gltf but none of them worked)
(I can't use .sfb or .sfa ,I can no longer use sceneform plugin  to convert files into sfa/sfb because it was deprecated)

here is my grade dependencies:

{

implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.15.0'

implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.15.0'

implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:assets:1.15.0'
...
}

My mainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.arcoretest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult;
import com.google.ar.core.Plane;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Renderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArFragment fragment;
    private Uri selectObject;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        selectObject = Uri.parse("testscene.obj");

        fragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sceneFormFragment);

        //when tapped on a plane, code below will run
        fragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
                (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent)->{
                    Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
                    placeObject(fragment,anchor,selectObject);
                }
        );
    }

    //this method put 3d model in scene
    private void placeObject(ArFragment fragment, Anchor anchor,Uri model){
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(fragment.getContext(),model)
                .build()
                .thenAccept( renderable -> addNodeToScene(fragment,anchor,renderable))
                .exceptionally((throwable -> {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage())
                            .setTitle("Error!");
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                    return null;
        }));
    }
    private void addNodeToScene(ArFragment fragment, Anchor anchor, Renderable renderable){
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(fragment.getTransformationSystem());
        node.setRenderable(renderable);
        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
        node.select();
    }

}
```

and I put my 3d model files in assets folder like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to update to the latest version of [SceneForm](https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/SceneformMaintained). This is a community maintained version, with the latest dependencies of ArCore, Filament and Android. For your usecase the [3d-model-viewer](https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/SceneformMaintained/tree/master/samples/3d-model-viewer) sample might be interesting.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I have to sponsor them to use it, which is understandable.
Are there any detailed tutorials about this version? All I want to do is just to show my simple 3d model in AR and rotate it

Comment: What I posted can be used for free. The sponsoring is just to help the dev-team to further improve this library, but you don't have to.

Comment: Cool! Are there any detailed tutorials about this version? All I want to do is just to show my simple 3d model in AR and let users rotate it

Comment: Only a primer on [Medium](https://medium.com/make-an-android-ar-augmented-reality-app-for/make-an-ar-augmented-reality-app-for-android-in-2022-48a1711562bb).

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into it